# Why does a structure type with an int field "forget" what value it is after the first time around a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

Why does the following code only work on the first iteration around the for loop?

```
typedef struct {
    char name[3];
    int gold, silver, bronze, total;
} tally_t;

int main(void)
{
    tally_t country[COUNTRIES_COMPETING];
    int j;
    j=0;
    country[j].gold=0;
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
        country[j].gold++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Op has not done the due diligence of debugging through the code first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you only initialized the `gold` member of the *first* element of the array. All the rest are uninitialized and have undefined values. Changing an undefined value is undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a way to initialize every element of the array?

Comment: a for loop that does country[j].gold=0... very similar to the loop you already have ;)

Comment: `tally_t country[COUNTRIES_COMPETING] = {{0}};` will initailize everything to 0 in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You just initialized the first element of your array of structure.

In order to fix your problem, you can do it like this :

```c
int main(void)
{
    tally_t country[COUNTRIES_COMPETING];
    int j;

    // Init Step
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        country[j].gold = 0:

    for (j=0; j<5; j++)
        country[j].gold++;
    return 0;
}
```